# java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

Tags: java, windows, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have added the certificate in Keystore, and I am trying to connect to the email exchange server using Java code. when I connect it throws a exception.

The same thing works fine when I execute the same Java code in eclipse but fails when i execute the same with the service it fails.

Here is my code:

```
public static void getEmailConnection(String folder){

try{

    Store store = null;
    Properties properties = System.getProperties();
    Folder emailFolder = null;

    final String SSL_FACTORY = "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory";
    String host = "HOST NAME";
    String username = "username";// change accordingly
    String password = "password";// change accordingly
    String mailStoreType = "pop3";
    String port = "1234";

    //Set manual Properties
    properties.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.class", SSL_FACTORY);
    properties.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    properties.setProperty("mail.pop3.socketFactory.port", port);
    properties.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", mailStoreType);
    properties.setProperty("mail.pop3.host", host);
    properties.setProperty("mail.pop3.port", port);


    Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
    //create the POP3 store object and connect with the pop server
    store = emailSession.getStore("pop3");
    store.connect(host,1234,username, password);

    emailFolder = store.getFolder(folder);
    emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

}catch(Exception e){
    throw new BsfConstraintViolationException("Unable to connect to Exchange Server",e);
    }
}
```

please find the below stack trace.

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
>       at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.(PKIXValidator.java:90)
>       at sun.security.validator.Validator.getInstance(Validator.java:179)
>       at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.getValidator(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:314)
>       at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedInit(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:173)
>       at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:186)
>       at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
>       at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1320)
>       at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:154)
>       at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
>       at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1032)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1328)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:882)
>       at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:102)
>       ... 24 more

Can any one please help me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you resolved that?

Comment: I had same problem, this worked for me: https://askubuntu.com/a/991636